# Remove list of phrases from string

Tags: python

I have an array of phrases:

```
bannedWords = ['hi', 'hi you', 'hello', 'and you']
```

I want to take a sentence like "hi, how are tim and you doing" and get this:

```
", how are tim doing"
```

Exact case matching is OK - sorry, should have clarified.

Comment: it is tricky, if the requirement is to replace "Hi" because "hi" is present in the list and leave "Tim" as "Tim".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to remove extra spaces as well, the regex below should work better:

```
s = "Hi, How are Tim and you doing"
bannedWords = ['hi', 'hi you', 'hello', 'and you']
for i in bannedWords: 
    s = re.sub(i + "\s*", '', s, flags = re.I)
print s
# ', How are Tim doing'
```

Comment: Previous versions artifact, removed.

Comment: Can you use the same wording as in my post? Which one of these is bannedWords?

Comment: @NBC changed. I'm afraid you're taking wrong approach to programming if you were going to copy-paste this without understand what it does.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with no issue, it's just good practice to make sure the answer matches the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` with a flag to do this in a case insensitive manner.

```
import re

bannedWords = ['hi', 'hi you', 'hello', 'and you']
sentence = "Hi, how are Tim and you doing"

new_sentence = re.sub('|'.join(bannedWords) + r'\s+', '', sentence, flags=re.I)
# new_sentence: ", how are Tim doing"
```

Comment: it will print something like `', How are Tim  doing'` with an extra space between `Tim` and `doing`.

Comment: Correct, this is fixed

Comment: I like those one better than mine, I haven't done any benchmarks, but this should be faster than looping over `bannedWords`.

Answer (score 1):

With regex you can join words you want to remove with |. We also want to remove any multiple blankspace with one blankspace. This ensures we only do two operations.

```
import re

def remove_banned(s,words):
    pattern = '|'.join(words)
    s = re.sub(pattern, '', s, flags = re.I) # remove words
    s = re.sub('\s+', ' ', s, flags = re.I) # remove extra blank space'
    return s

bannedWords = ['hi', 'hi you', 'hello', 'and you']
s = "Hi, How are Tim and you doing"

print(remove_banned(s,bannedWords))
```

Returns:

```
, How are Tim doing
```