# Remove a list of phrase from string

Tags: python, string, text

I have a list of phrases (n-grams) that need to be removed from a given sentence.

```
    removed = ['range', 'drinks', 'food and drinks', 'summer drinks']
    sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks'
```

I want to get:

```
    new_sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide of'
```

I tried [Remove list of phrases from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937718/remove-list-of-phrases-from-string) but it doesn't work ('Oranges' turns into 'Os', 'drinks' is removed instead of a phrase 'food and drinks')

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: You probably should be using a natural language processing library for this if you need to handle plurals.

Comment: do you tried loop through the removed list and detect for each index if it's in the sentence ?

Comment: You can solve the second problem by sorting the `removed` list with the longer phrases first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression time!

```
In [116]: removed = ['range', 'drinks', 'food and drinks', 'summer drinks']
     ...: removed = sorted(removed, key=len, reverse=True)
     ...: sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks'
     ...: new_sentence = sentence
     ...: import re
     ...: removals = [r'\b' + phrase + r'\b' for phrase in removed]
     ...: for removal in removals:
     ...:     new_sentence = re.sub(removal, '', new_sentence)
     ...: new_sentence = ' '.join(new_sentence.split())
     ...: print(sentence)
     ...: print(new_sentence)
Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks
Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide of
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to match on whole words only, I think the first step is to turn everything into lists of words, and then iterate from longest to shortest phrase in order to find things to remove:

```
>>> removed = ['range', 'drinks', 'food and drinks', 'summer drinks']
>>> sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks'
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> for ngram in sorted([r.split() for r in removed], key=len, reverse=True):
...     for i in range(len(words) - len(ngram)+1):
...         if words[i:i+len(ngram)] == ngram:
...             words = words[:i] + words[i+len(ngram):]
...             break
...
>>> " ".join(words)
'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide of'
```

Note that there are some flaws with this simple approach -- multiple copies of the same n-gram won't be removed, but you can't continue with that loop after modifying `words` either (the length will be different), so if you want to handle duplicates, you'll need to batch the updates.

Comment: Thanks, @Samwise, it works for my given example. Unfortunately, my real data has duplicates, is there any way to overcome it?

Comment: As suggested, batch the updates; instead of modifying `words` inside that loop and breaking, add `i` to a list and continue.  Then do the modification to everything in the list all at once.  Alternatively, do that iteration in reverse order (i.e. reverse the range) and then you can modify the list without breaking the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re

    removed = ['range', 'drinks', 'food and drinks', 'summer drinks']
    sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks'

    # sort the removed tokens according to their length,
    removed = sorted(removed, key=len, reverse=True)

    # using word boundaries
    for r in removed:
        sentence = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(r), " ", sentence)

    # replace multiple whitspaces with a single one   
    sentence = re.sub(' +',' ',sentence)
```

I hope this would help:
first, you need to sort the removed strings according to their length, in this way 'food and drinks' will be replaced before 'drinks'

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

```
removed = ['range', 'drinks', 'food and drinks', 'summer drinks','are']
sentence = 'Oranges are the main ingredient for a wide range of food and drinks'

words = sentence.split()
resultwords  = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in removed]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
print(result)
```

Results:

```
Oranges the main ingredient for a wide of food and
```

Comment: You didn't remove `food and drinks`, which is same problem he has.